# Bootstrap 768px media query not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I am trying to make a responsive bootstrap navigation bar, but there is a problem when it is collapsed. The css makes my collapsed navbar look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPYrq.jpg).

I want to make a meda query so when the navbar collapse happens(768px), all the css from these 3 elements will disapear so they will show normal(the bbbbbbb go out of the screen and there are 2 scrolls on the bottom and right that I would like to disappear), but when I write my code, nothing happends

HTML:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="colnav">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="navright">
                        <li><a href="#" id="a">aaaaaaa</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" id="b">bbbbbbb</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" id="c">ccccccc</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

CSS:

```
#a
{
    padding: 20px 40px 20px 40px;
    text-transform: uppercase; 
}

#b
{
    padding: 20px 40px 20px 40px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: auto -5px auto -40px;
}

#c
{
    padding: 20px 35px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: rgb(255, 165, 0);
    color: snow;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Media query CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) 
{
    #a 
    {
       padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    #b
    {
       padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    #c
    {
       padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
}
```

But nothing seems to happen

EDIT: Here is a codepen codepen.io/anon/pen/zoqwJO

Comment: can you add a screen shot of what your expected output is

Comment: If you can add a fiddle or codepen would be lot helpful

Comment: @Geeky here is a codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zoqwJO . I just want it so when the navbar is collapsed and I open it, all the items to be displayed without css because the current css distorts them

Comment: Just check is this what you want http://codepen.io/sahithiK/pen/bBpWZj

Comment: @Geeky yeah, please post it as an anser so I can accept it

Comment: please consider accepting answer if it helped u any way

Answer (score 0):

See below

```css
.navbar-nav {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.navbar li a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
@media(min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar li a {
    padding: 20px 40px 20px 40px;
  }      
}
.navbar li.active a {
  background-color: rgb(255, 165, 0) !important;
  color: snow !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="./">aaaaaaaa <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">bbbbbbb</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ccccccc</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fjh3mvgv/

Also, I would suggest when using media queries style mobile up and have the classes not in the query be the base styling then style up. e.g.:

```
.someclass {
  padding: 2em;
}

@media(min-width: 768px) {
  .someclass {
    padding: 1em;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check this snippet

```css
#a {
  padding: 20px 40px 20px 40px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#b {
  padding: 20px 40px 20px 40px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: auto -5px auto -40px;
}
#c {
  padding: 20px 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: rgb(255, 165, 0);
  color: snow;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #a {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-transform: none;
  }
  #b {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-transform: none
  }
  #c {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-transform: none;
    color: inherit;
    background: transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!--LOADER-->
  <div class="loader"></div>
  <!--NAVBAR-->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top shad" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" id="colbtn" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#colnav" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="colnav">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="navright">
          <li><a href="#" id="a" role="link">aaaaaaa</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#" id="b" role="link">bbbbbbb</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#" id="c" role="button">ccccccc</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope it helps